# Алгоритм проверки, является ли элемент частью множества

Tags: хеширование

У меня есть список элементов который я хочу хешировать вместе, чтобы получить хеш корня (аналогично merkle-дереву). Требование состоит в том, что мне нужно проверить присутствует ли элемент в хеше корня. Сейчас ограничение в том, что, я буду иметь доступ только к хешу корня и элементу который нам нужно проверить в любой момент времени, поэтому мы не сможем использовать подход merkle-дерева. Испробовали bloom-фильтры и подобные алгоритмы но так и не смог найти способ обрабатывать ложные положительные. Есть ли какая-то структура данных или алгоритм которым я могу следовать, чтобы получить решение?

количество элементов превышает 300.000.000+ и нет возможности хранить полный набор

Comment: Поместите хеши в отдельный хешсет.

Comment: количество элементов превышает 300.000.000 и нет возможности хранить полный набор.

Comment: Поместите хеши в таблицу базы данных.

Comment: набор элементов будет занимать терабайты, так что это не вариант.

Comment: 300 миллионов 64-битых чисел - это три гигабайта. В Питоне hashset на 300 миллионов занимает 17 гигабайт. Специализированный hashset займёт в три раза меньше. Аналогичное место займёт таблица на диске.

Comment: набор может и увеличиться 300м+ и каковы будут затраты на сравнение такого hashset по времени?

Comment: Сама проверка делается за константу. Обновление hashset делается за то же время что и обновление дерева хешей. Если вы решите строить хешсет с нуля, то на моей машине это занимает несколько секунд.

Comment: Ещё раз повторюсь - таблица в базе данных тоже отлично справится.

Comment: Постгрес поддерживает hash indices - у вас будет тот же хешсет только на диске.